# Using AFIncrementalStore without NSFetchedResultsController or NSArrayController

Tags: core-data, afincrementalstore

I'm trying to fetch some data without NSFetchedResultsController or NSArrayController. The problem is that due to AFIncrementalStore's asynchronous nature, I'm always getting stale data (or no data if it hasn't been fetched) data.

Is there any recommended approach to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that preferred approach to this problem is to use `NSFetchedResultsControllers` (at least on iOS). If you really don't want to use it, you might want to subscribe to one of these notifications, depending on the granularity of changes you expect to receive:

- `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`
- `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`

and then refetch the data when one of these notifications is posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the AFIncrementalStore notification for notification on when remote data has been fetched in order to update the UI and your objects.

`AFIncrementalStoreContextDidFetchRemoteValues` etc

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/blob/master/AFIncrementalStore/AFIncrementalStore.m#L29